# Articles with abstract nouns

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

Given:

> In the world of ***a* flourishing** globalization

Which sort of article should be used before *flourishing* — zero, definite, or indefinite?

Comment: I'd say the example sounds unnatural, coupling 'flourishing' with 'globalisation', especially after 'the world of'. Choosing between articles then becomes irrelevant. 'In the flourishing world of globalisation' seems less strange.

Comment: Thank you. I' ve always though that if an adjectives preceeds a noun indefinite aticle should be used.

Comment: That's by no means a general rule with noncount nouns. For example, though 'The professor spoke at the meeting today with an enormous enthusiasm.' is by no means incorrect, neither is 'The professor spoke at the meeting today with enormous enthusiasm.'

Comment: an adjective* in singular

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try:

> In a world of flourishing globalization ...

Comment: Changing the first article improves this greatly.

Comment: @Edwin: Surely it depends on context? *In **the** world of flourishing globalization* would be a more suitable introductory phrase if you were going to continue with some statement about *how things appear **from the perspective of** globalized industries/companies*. Using ***a*** might be more appropriate if you were saying something about how such a world appears from *other* perspectives.

Comment: @FF 'In the world of NP' doesn't accept a descriptor (as opposed to a classifier [in the world of nuclear physics]) pre-modifying adjective too idiomatically. ??In the world of fascinating nanotechnology. –